# Sum up values(currency) from the list

Tags: soql, list, loop, decimal, sum

```
Decimal totalReceived = 0.00;

List<Money_Received__c> moneyReceived = [Select Amount_Received__c,Reservation__r.Total_Recieved__c from Money_Received__c where Id =: reservationId];


        for(Money_Received__c receivedMoney : moneyReceived ){
            if (totalReceived == 0.00){
                totalReceived += Money_Received__c.Amount_Received__c;
            }
        }
```

Amount_Received__c is a custom field(type currency).
When user input multiple 'Amount_Received__c' into a table, it should sum up to 'totalReceived'

how can I get the numeric values from Amount_Received__c ??

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.

## First Only

Your if statement means that you're only going to get the first non-zero value in the list. That's probably not what you want if you're trying to sum multiple values.

## Field Reference vs Object Reference

You need to refer to the field on a record, not the static field reference that represents the field's metadata.

---

```
for(Money_Received__c receivedMoney : moneyReceived ){
    totalReceived += receivedMoney.Amount_Received__c;
}
```

Comment: I got an error when I tried receivedMoney.Amount_Received__c, but not is works..Thank you!!

Comment: What do I need to change if I want to sum values whenever Amount_Received__c is updated?

Comment: @LoganH you need to call the method when the value changes. This is usually done with an "actionSupport" element in your Visualforce page.